# href angularjs not routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, routes

I have defined my href links like this:

```
   <div id="left-menu">
      <div class="sub-left-menu scroll">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li><div class="left-bg"></div></li>
            <li class="time">
              <h1 class="animated fadeInLeft">21:00</h1>
              <p class="animated fadeInRight">Sat,October 1st 2029</p>
            </li>
            <li class="active ripple">
              <a href="#hosts">
                  <span class="fa-home fa"></span> Dashboard
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ripple">
                <a href="hosts/hosts.html">
                    <span class="fa fa-calendar-o"></span> Calendar
                </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

However when I click on the `<a>` tags it does not seem to pull back the content held within the my hosts.html file.  The url in the browser also does not change with the base url being `http://localhost/dashboard/#/main` and when I click host the desired output should be `http://localhost/dashboard/#/hosts` with the correct content displaying.  Here is the theme pack I am using http://akivaron.github.io/miminium/

Here are my angularjs files starting with the app itself 'dashApp'

```
'use strict'

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular.module('dashApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'dashApp.main',
  'dashApp.hosts'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/main'});
}]);
```

here is my main:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('dashApp.main', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/main', {
    templateUrl: 'main/main.html',
    controller: 'mainController'
  })
}])

.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http, $window){

});
```

and here is my hosts file:

```
'use strict'

angular.module('dashApp.hosts', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/hosts', {
    templateUrl: 'hosts/hosts.html',
    controller: 'hostsController'
  })
}])

.controller('hostsController', function($scope, $http, $window){
});
```

and here is the project structure:
https://gyazo.com/fb5e2a2651fe8cc460fde783237ddd9c

Answer (score 1):

Remove the trailing `/` in the href's. They need to match the url in your routing config

Example

```
<a class="tree-toggle nav-header" href="#/main/" target="_self">
```

Should be

```
<a class="tree-toggle nav-header" href="#/main" >
```

Comment: This did not seem to solve the problem, it still does the same thing as mentioned in my post

Comment: Are you sure template path is correct? Add a route change error handler and get error details. Also have you included an `ng-view` in main page?

Comment: where do I implement this?  In the app or the main module?

Comment: This answer should fix your problem. You have your routes wrong in the hrefs.

Comment: @charlietfl error handler, I do have an ng-view in my main page

Comment: Set it up in an angular `run` block.

Comment: @charlietfl I am not sure how to go about doing this as I am new to angularjs, I will add my project directory as an image to this post to make sure I am pointing to the correct template path

Answer (score 1):

"Href" links should be inside ng-app and ng-view also inside the app. Like Below

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <a href="#/home">home</a>
    <a href="#/book">books</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

first of all check the above then update your js file like below:-

```
var app=angular.module("myApp",['ngRoute']);
app.config('$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider
   .when('/home',{
     templateUrl:'path/some.html'
    })
});
```

feel free to ask if any doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the hash.

```
<a class="tree-toggle nav-header" href="/main">link</a>
```

Comment: That did not work either, I have tried putting in a static url to google and that did not work either when I clicked on it

Comment: Maybe `ng-href` should have a different output. I'm sorry I can't try right now.

Comment: Nope that did not work either, when I click on the links it does not do anything at all.

Comment: can you try to make a jsfiddle, plunkr or codepen of your exact code, would be esier to understand.

Comment: I don't think this is an angular problem,  I can right click and open in new tab and this works.  I think maybe a css problem? something over the top of my links that is preventing me from clicking them?  I am using a theme pack and trying to integrate it with angular,  I will update the post with the current HTML markup and the themepack I am using